# How to access the data from mapping table in graphql using sequelize

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js, graphql-js

i am new to sequelize, i have a user table , address table and address type table as given below. 
A **user** can have 2 a different **address** , permanent and current address, and the type of address (permanent or current ) is specified in the table **address type**.

I have tried to access the data from mapping table (address_type) in the resolver based on schema and set **hasMany** relation from user -> address table , but graphql shows association not found error. 
How can we get the relation properly in order to get the mapping address type name.

```
        type User{
          id:Int
          name:String             
        }

        type Address {
          id: ID!
          user_id:Int
          city: String
          addr_type:AddressType
        }

        type AddressType{
         id : Int
         name:String (permanent|current)
        }
```

table definition

```
            module.exports = function(sequelize, DataTypes) {
            return sequelize.define('user', {
            id: {
                    type: DataTypes.INTEGER, allowNull: false, primaryKey: true, autoIncrement: true
                },
                name: {
                    type: DataTypes.INTEGER,  allowNull: false, 
                }, 
            }, {
                tableName: 'user',
                timestamps: false
            });
        };


        module.exports = function(sequelize, DataTypes) {
            return sequelize.define('address', {
            id: {
                    type: DataTypes.INTEGER, allowNull: false, primaryKey: true, autoIncrement: true
                },
                user_id: {
                    type: DataTypes.INTEGER,  allowNull: false, field:"addr_type"   
                },
                addr_type: {
                    type: DataTypes.INTEGER,  allowNull: false, field:"addr_type"   
                },
                city: {
                    type: DataTypes.STRING,  allowNull: false,
                }, 

            }, {
                tableName: 'address',
                timestamps: false

            });
        };

        module.exports = function(sequelize, DataTypes) {
            return sequelize.define('address_types', {
            id: {
                    type: DataTypes.INTEGER, allowNull: false, primaryKey: true, autoIncrement: true
                },
                name: {
                    type: DataTypes.STRING, allowNull: false, 
                },
            }, {
                tableName: 'address_type',
                timestamps: false

            });
        };
```

relationship

```
db.user.hasMany(db.address,{foreignKey: 'user_id'});
db.address.belongsTo(db.user,{foreignKey: 'user_id'});
db.address.belongsTo(db.address_types,{foreignKey: 'addr_type'});
```

resolver code

```
            userts: async (obj, args, context, info ) =>    User.findAll( {
                        where: { user_status: 1 },          
                ,
                raw: true,
                nest: true,
        } ).then(userts => {
        const response = userts.map(usert => {                       
        return{
        // i have 15 fields for a user, if i can access the schema of the corresponsing resolver i can dynamically build the response out put

                   id: usert.id,
                   firstName: usert.firstName,
                   lastName: usert.lastName,
                   middleName: usert.middleName,


        }
        })                      
            return response;
        }),
```

Comment: can you show a sequelize query you trying to execute?

Comment: added resolver code @Anatoly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should turn off the option **raw** in order to get associated objects and use the **include** option to indicate what associated models you wish to load.

```
User.findAll( {
  where: { user_status: 1 },          
                include: [{ 
                  model: Address,
                  include: AddressType
                }],
                raw: false,
                nest: true,
        }
```